# Warning in Rsolnp : Solution not reliable because unable to Invert Hessian

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, hessian-matrix

I am trying to understand why do I get warning messages while trying to solve this using solnp? Following is the message I get -

```
solnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.
Warning message:
In p0 * vscale[(neq + 2):(nc + np + 1)] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Following is the code

```
countw <- 100
Dmat = diag(1, 100, 100)
# Equality constraints
eq_A <- rep(1, countw)
eq_b <- 1

# Constraint wts greater than zero
ineq_A <- diag(x = 1, nrow = countw, ncol = countw)
ineq_b <- rep(0, countw)

# Combine constraints
heq <- eq_A
hin <- ineq_A

theta <- c(0.51, 0.49, rep(0, countw-2))

krdsolnp <- solnp(par = theta, 
                  fun = function(x) -c(t(x) %*% Dmat %*% x), 
                  ineqfun = function(x) c(hin %*% x),
                  ineqLB = rep(0, countw),
                  ineqUB = rep(1, countw),
                  eqfun = function(x) c(heq %*% x),
                  eqB = eq_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code amounts to asking:  how can I maximize *sum(x^2)*, while keeping the coefficients of *x* between 0 and 1, and keeping *sum(x)* equal to 1?

The library tries to solve this using the Hessian of the target function, i.e. the matrix of partial derivatives of *sum(x^2)* with respect to any pair of coefficients of *x*.  That Hessian would ordinarily be 2 times the identity matrix, which is invertible.

However, something about the constraints throws this off.  You can avoid the error by changing the 0's in the initial condition *theta* to 0.01's.